# Python Check if its possible to reach right most end of the array by hop left or right

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am writing a program that finds if a game is solvable or not solvable.
The rules of the game are:

1. You start from the leftmost position
2. You can hop left or right by the value of the array at the position and you cannot go beyond the endpoints.  Ex:  a={4,4,1,5,2,6,3,4,2,0}  you start from left most position so you can jump 4 places right to 2(left is not possible)
3. I have to check if we can reach other end which is always equal to 0.
4. If we can reach the rightmost (i.e 0) then it is solvable else not solvable

I have  tried using recursion in Python, but have no idea how to proceed

```
 def KAuhop(b,c,d,current_position):
        position_move=b[current_position]
        if b[current_position+position_move]==0:
            print("found")
        else:
            KAuhop(b,current_position+position_move,d,current_position)
            print("Not found")




    a=[4,4,1,5,2,6,3,4,2,0]
    print(KAuhop(a,0,len(a)-1,0))
```

Comment: wait, you have c and d as a parameter.. but you never use it in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can jump positions either left or right, then please mention when the program should end or exit else it'll become infinite loop jumping from one position to another.

Please find the below solution for only right jumps using recursive function.

```
lis=[4,4,1,5,2,4,3,4,2,0]
last_pos=len(lis)-1
pos = 0+lis[0]

def kauhop(lis,pos):
    if (pos==last_pos):
        print("found")
        exit;
    else:
        new_pos = pos+lis[pos]
        if(new_pos <= last_pos):
            kauhop(lis,new_pos)
        else:
            print("Not found")

kauhop(lis,pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we that keeps track of positions you've already seen in a `set` object:

```
In [25]: def kauhop(seq):
    ...:     seen = set()
    ...:     maxlen = len(seq) - 1
    ...:     def helper(pos):
    ...:         if pos > maxlen or pos < 0 or pos in seen:
    ...:             return False
    ...:         elif pos == maxlen:
    ...:             return True
    ...:         else:
    ...:             jump = seq[pos]
    ...:             seen.add(pos)
    ...:             left = helper(pos - jump)
    ...:             right = helper(pos + jump)
    ...:             return left or right
    ...:     return helper(0)
    ...:

In [26]: kauhop(a)
Out[26]: True
```

Essentially, you can use recursion to check every possible path. Consider your current position: if you are out of bounds in either direction, or you've already checked that position (it's in `seen`), then return `False`. Otherwise,  mark the position as seen, check a left jump, and a right jump, and return if either left or right is a success. Note: I use an helper inner function. This lets me not have to keep passing the `seen` set around, since the `helper` is closed over `seen`, and for that matter, `maxlen`.

Now I'm wondering if there is a better approach than brute-force.